# How to deep copy a FormArray entry in Angular2 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'd like to take a deep copy of a FormGroup object which is an entry in a FormArray object.

I am using the recommended way of deep copying objects in typescript but it is still pointing to the original object reference.
I could solve the problem by copying every single field one by one. but I'd like to know if there is a better approach to achieve this.

Here is my code, the commented line is the one which didn't perform the deep copy behavior as expected:

```
edit(i): void {
  this.activeEntry=i;
  const mycontrol = <FormArray>this.languagesForm.controls['languages'];
  const mylanguage=<FormGroup>mycontrol.get([i]);
  //this.languageEditForm = Object.assign(new FormGroup({}),<FormGroup>mycontrol.get([i]));

  this.languageEditForm = this.fb.group({
    name:mylanguage.get('name').value,
    type:mylanguage.get('type').value,
    listening:mylanguage.get('listening').value,
    reading:mylanguage.get('reading').value,
    speaking:mylanguage.get('speaking').value,
    writing:mylanguage.get('writing').value
  });

  console.log(this.languageEditForm.value);
  this.showDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.assign()` does not really create a full deep copy following the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

As all your controls are again only objects they will be just referenced by the "cloned" object.

Maybe the `lodash _.cloneDeep()` cloud help here?!

Comment: This does not look like a valid answer. have you tested `lodash _.cloneDeep()` ?